# Adding segue to a split view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

my app has a a home screen (mainly a view with buttons on it). when a user presses one of the buttons, the view should segue to another view. it happens that one of the views that i want to segue to should be a split view controller. i tried adding the split view in storyboard and run the app, it returns with errors: either i'm presenting the split view modally or i can't add the split view if the view before it is embedded in a navigation controller. How can i achieve adding a split view if there's a view before or a navigation controller view?

Comment: Yor question is so confuse. Take a print screen and explain that interaction

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH7-SW1) split view controllers must always be the root view:

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window. The panes of your split view interface may then contain navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view controller you need to implement your interface. Split view controllers cannot be presented modally.
>
> The easiest way to integrate a split view controller into your application is to start from a new project. The Split View-based Application template in Xcode provides a good starting point for building an interface that incorporates a split view controller.

Comment: thanks. i did it a clone of a split using two container view controllers.